# Find all my post that are tagged as C++

Tags: support, tag-search, user-search

I decided to review all my contributions to the C++ tag for the sake of self improvement hence I am wondering how to find all the posts that I have contributed to in the C++ tag.

How can I find them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile and click [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in the Tags list.  Or provide the [appropriate custom search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1832057+[c%2b%2b]) manually.